# how to save PID when executing multiple shell script from one shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Lets say I have 3 shell scripts `First.sh` , `Second.sh` and `Third.sh`. Then I created

`Forth.sh` with the content

```
nohup sh First.sh &
nohup sh Second.sh &
nohup sh Third.sh &
```

How to save PID created by each of the nohup command when I run `nohup sh Forth.sh` ?

thanks for you time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$!` right after you issue the `nohup`. It should return the child-pid. It will be overwritten every time you fork a child process.

Alternatively, you could save `$$` from the child process (e.g. First.sh, Second.sh ...)

```sh
nohup sh First.sh &
FIRST_PID=$!
nohup sh Second.sh &
SECOND_PID=$!
nohup sh Third.sh &
THIRD_PID=$!
```